# Thrown system.exception.stackoverflowexception C#

Tags: c#, winforms

In my C# windows form application, there is a combo box that has 3 options in it, when selecting second one a switch command that checks options of another combo box throws and exception of type stack overflow, with this details:

[image: image here]

> System.StackOverflowException occurred
>
> HResult=0x800703E9
>         Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
>         StackTrace:
>        <Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>

Update:

this is the event of index change in combo box:

```
private void cmbxDoorType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cmbxDoorType.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            chkTopBlock.Enabled = true;
            if(chkTopBlock.Checked)
                cmbxTopBlockConfig.Enabled = true;
            cmbxTopSideConfig.Enabled = true;
            txtDoorHeight.ReadOnly = false;
            txtTotalWidth.Visible = false;
            lblTotalWidth.Visible = false;
            lblDoorBaleWidth.Enabled = false;

        }
        else if (cmbxDoorType.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            txtTotalWidth.Visible = false;
            lblTotalWidth.Visible = false;
            lblDoorBaleWidth.Enabled = false;
            cmbxTopBlockConfig.Enabled = false;
            chkTopBlock.Enabled = false;
            txtDoorHeight.ReadOnly = true;
            cmbxTopSideConfig.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            chkTopBlock.Enabled = true;
            if (chkTopBlock.Checked)
                cmbxTopBlockConfig.Enabled = true;
            cmbxTopSideConfig.Enabled = true;
            txtDoorHeight.ReadOnly = false;
            txtTotalWidth.Visible = true;
            lblTotalWidth.Visible = true;
            lblDoorBaleWidth.Enabled = true;

        }
        Prediction();
    }
```

this is the prediction methode than exception ocours in:

```
internal void Prediction ()
    {
        if (Globals.ProjectType=="Gama")
        {
            int TotalHeight_=0;
            double DesignHeight_=0;
            int TotalWidth_=0;
            double LeftDis = 0;
            double RightDis = 0;
            double RowsTotalHeight_=0;
            double TopBlockHeight_=0;
            double thisDoorHeight_ = 0;
            int DoorHeight_=0;
            int DoorWidth_=0;
            double DoorBaleWidth_=0;
            try
            {
                switch (cmbxLeftSideConfig.SelectedIndex)  //exception thrown here
                {
                    case 0:
                        LeftDis = GamaGlobals.Constants.BeamThickness - GamaGlobals.Constants.InsertOffset;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        LeftDis = GamaGlobals.Constants.GP115Body + GamaGlobals.Constants.BeamThickness - GamaGlobals.Constants.InsertOffset;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        LeftDis = GamaGlobals.Constants.GP114Body + GamaGlobals.Constants.BeamThickness - GamaGlobals.Constants.InsertOffset;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        LeftDis = GamaGlobals.Constants.GP117Height - GamaGlobals.Constants.InsertOffset;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        LeftDis = 0;
                        break;
                }

                switch (cmbxRightSideConfig.SelectedIndex)
                {
                    case 0:
                        RightDis = GamaGlobals.Constants.BeamThickness - GamaGlobals.Constants.InsertOffset;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        RightDis = GamaGlobals.Constants.GP115Body + GamaGlobals.Constants.BeamThickness - GamaGlobals.Constants.InsertOffset;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        RightDis = GamaGlobals.Constants.GP114Body + GamaGlobals.Constants.BeamThickness - GamaGlobals.Constants.InsertOffset;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        RightDis = GamaGlobals.Constants.GP117Height - GamaGlobals.Constants.InsertOffset;
                        break;


     case 1:
                            RightDis = 0;
                            break;
                    }
}
```

Comment: Please share your code. We can't help you without it.

Comment: @Mureinik Updated

Comment: Are you changing the index/binding on page load?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning  i am assigning some default values for all items on page load. but default index for cmbxDoortype is 0, and this exception occurs when index is 1,it works fine when index=2 too.

Answer (score 0):

Something in your `cmbxDoorType_SelectedIndexChanged`, or another `SelectedIndexChanged` event will retrigger your event again, which makes it a `StackOverFlowException` after a couple of seconds

Answer (score 0):

in "prediction" method there was a line that changes a textbox value, and that text box itself has a value changed event that triggers "prediction" again.

so it's solved.

just as another question, is there a way to change textbox/numericupdown controls value programmatically without triggering its change event?
for example, if the user changes it, it triggers event but when its programmatically changed, the event does not trigger.
hm??

Comment: not that I'm aware of. A common workaorund is to keep a flag "I'm modifying the text from code", and test it in the textbox_changed event handler